Extraction of Parents by hierarchy for employees using Azure Synapse Analytics
I am looking for a solution for the below situation:
I have to extract all the managers (by hierarchy) for some employees that i receive in the flow (we have a file that contains all the information about all the employees and an other that represent the current delta of the flow), context of files they are stored in the datalake (csv files) , i am working with Azure SQL pool of Synapse to query the files. I am not able to use recursive tables (CTE) as it is not supported in Synapse.
Could you have some other ideas to get the ascendants of each employee in the flow? thank you

Recursive CTE is not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics. You can use a While loop to achieve the same requirement that recursive CTE does. While loop is supported in Azure Synapse Analytics Dedicated SQL pool.

Create an external table for the file that is stored in Data Lake.

For this demo, I created a sample external table as below.





Employee_id
Manager_id




E12345
M123


M123
M456


M456
M789


M789






In order to get all the ascendants of a given employee, you can follow the below T-SQL script.

DECLARE @EmployeeID VARCHAR(10) = 'E12345';
DECLARE @ManagerID VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @ManagerHierarchy VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @ManagerID = Manager_id
FROM ext_EmployeeHierarchy
WHERE Employee_id = @EmployeeID;

WHILE @ManagerID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ManagerHierarchy = CONCAT(@ManagerHierarchy, ' -> ', @ManagerID);
    SELECT @ManagerID = Manager_id
    FROM ext_EmployeeHierarchy
    WHERE Employee_id = @ManagerID;
END

SELECT SUBSTRING(@ManagerHierarchy, 4, LEN(@ManagerHierarchy) - 1) AS ManagerHierarchy;

The WHILE loop here iterates through the hierarchy by repeatedly querying the EmployeeHierarchy table for the manager ID of the current employee ID. It appends each manager ID to the @ManagerHierarchy variable, separated by a separator (->).
Output:



ManagerHierarchy




M123 -> M456 -> M789



